# Rotating 1 bit bitmap for lcd screen

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino, atmega

I'm storing some custom characters for a Hitachi HD44780 LCD controller in an array on my microcontroller (Arduino Mega). A character is basically a bitmap with a color depth of one bit and is 5 px wide and 8 px high.

To save as much precious memory as possible, I decided to store the data rotated. Otherwise I would waste three bits per row. So for example, an É would be stored like this:

```
---#####   0x1F
-#-#-#-#   0x55
#--#-#-#   0x95
---#-#-#   0x15
---#---#   0x11
```

The output should look like this:

```
-----#--   0x04
----#---   0x08
--------   0x00
---#####   0x1F
---#----   0x10
---####-   0x1E
---#----   0x10
---#####   0x1F
```

My question is, what's the most efficient way to turn this back around into an É. We're talking about a 16 MHz processor with only 8 KB of RAM here, so keeping it as fast and tiny as possible is the key. The programming language is C(++).

My personal idea was to create the required array of 8 bytes and scan the lines from left to right, setting the bits with some bit masks. That's why I also mirrored the letters, so that I can easily shift my bitmask right and use it for both arrays.

Basically scan the first input byte, set the 3rd bits of the output array accordingly, scan the second line, set the 4th bits of the output array and so on.

But is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: So the top array is an 5 row, 8 bit array.  the bottom is a 8 row, 5 bit array rotated from the first, with the 5 bit array having 3 zero bits on the left.  Which constraint is more important? speed or code size?

Comment: The code you'll use to rotate it could be used store it, and then some.  You could store these in PROGRMEM conventionally and use less space.

Comment: Use `uint8_t bitmap[5]`, not of rotated data, but _packed_ bit data.  Easier to unpack those 40 bit as 5 bytes into 8 bytes than un-rotate.  Post the code that shows what you have tried to not make this post too broad.

Comment: Using "macro-magic" `const` data could look like `uint8_t letter[5] = FOO5(X__1__, X_1___, X_____, X11111, X1____, X1111_, X1____, X11111)`.  Formated, the data would look like the letter.

Comment: @EvilTeach As far as I know, the three bits to the left are just ignored by the display controller. I think that space is more important than speed.

Comment: @TomServo The font will be stored in PROGMEM. The char table is much bigger in reality.

Comment: @chux What do you mean with packed bit data? Basically ignore the three unnecessary bits? Like 00100 010|00 00000 1|1111 1000|0 11110 10|000 11111?

How would I unpack that efficiently? Just by shifting bits?

Comment: @AndréR. Be fair, what does [your code look like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537419/rotating-1-bit-bitmap-for-lcd-screen?noredirect=1#comment78035294_45537419)?  Else this post is simply asking someone to write code for you.

Comment: Overengineering?  I think the LCD can only have like 8 custom characters loaded at a time.  Your scheme to rotate the characters in your AVR's memory would only save 3 bytes per character, so that would be 24 bytes (assuming you aren't swapping your customer characters in and out of the LCD).  You should store the characters in program memory, and your Arduino Mega has tons of that (256 KB).  Any compression you add to your data needs corresponding code to decompress it, which takes up flash.

Comment: @DavidGrayson My font has a size of around 3 KB compressed. Do you think, that the decompression code would be larger than that?

Comment: @chux I'm not asking for code, I'm asking for ideas how to make it most efficient. Your idea to not store it rotated, but simply compressed is one of those ideas.

Comment: You have a 3KB font and 256 KB of flash?  You still probably don't need any compression, but sure you can probably save flash space.  You know the LCD has its own built in font you can use, right?  And you can only use 8 custom characters at a time (of the 384 in your font).  So if you want more than 8 different characters in the screen, you must use the built in font.

Comment: How about packing 8 characters (each 5-pixels wide) into 5 bytes (each 8-bits wide). Extracting a character would masking bits from two adjacent bytes and a bit of shifting. The masks/shifts could possibly be calculated on-the-fly or simply taken from a small lookup table. You probably don't need to make a "special case" for the first and last character of each group of five (where all five bits come from a single byte) -- you just ensure the 2nd byte's mask is all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you.  This is the most interesting question I have seen in months.

So space is the constraint.  As I see it the major problem is that there is a cost to bit extraction and insertion that will eat up code memory pretty fast.  A loop extracting a single bit from an array of 5 bytes, inserting into an array of 8 bytes could require a good hunk of executable code to do that.

I suggest a different way to represent the data is to support a kind of [run-length encoding.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) The output character can be thought as a single bit string, consisting of a stream of 0/1s, followed by other  streams of 0/1s until 64 bits have been filled.

In effect you are encoding the state changes, rather the actual bit pattern.
The data would be 1 bit wide, to indicate 0 or 1, with a length of 3 bits wide to represent length 1 .. 8.

hence with

```
-----#--   0x04
----#---   0x08
--------   0x00
---#####   0x1F
```

The encoding would be

- 0101 - 0 bit, a total of 6 bit positions, encoded as 6 - 1 (------)
- 1000 - 1 bit, a total of 1 bit positions, encoded as 1 - 1 (#)
- 0101 - 0 bit, a total of 6 bit positions, encoded as 6 - 1 (------)
- 1000 - 1 bit, a total of 1 bit positions, encoded as 1 - 1 (#)
- 0111 - 0 bit, a total of 8 bit positions, encoded as 8 - 1 (--------)
- 0101 - 0 bit, a total of 6 bit positions, encoded as 6 - 1 (------)
- 1100 - 1 bit, a total of 5 bit positions, encoded as 5 - 1 (#####)

That's 3.5 bytes instead of 4 bytes to encode.

---

A variation on the theme, is to not encode the leading 3 bits on each byte.  When the executable code comes to that, it automatically puts the three 0s into it.  That would drop the encoding cost of the little example above to about 2.5 bytes at the cost of some extra executable code.

I think the benefit here is that you are pulling exactly bits from one nibble of the byte each time, and dropping them into bits of a single byte.  IMNSHO that is going to get the biggest size bang for the buck.

Comment: One of the downsides of this, is that there is no obvious method to tell where the encoding for a specific character starts.

Comment: That's true. I would always need a pointer to the start address of the character in the array anyways. But with the run-length encoding, I would either need to store an additional bit offset inside of that byte, or I would need to pad the encoded characters, so the start of a character always falls on the first bit of a byte. I wonder, if that would really save some space. With the padding, I would waste 7 bits per char in the worst case. With the offset, I would always waste 8 bits, because there is no half byte in C, as far as I'm concerned. Or is there some math magic?

Comment: if you are looking at processing 256 characters only, you could store them sequentially, then to find character 14, you start at the top of the list, and scan through 13 characters, then you would be pointed at the 14th.  That avoids the extra memory at the cost of extra processing.

Comment: Do you have an approximation of how big the performance impact would be, to scan through all the 256 characters in the worst case? Another way would be to use a kind of hybrid solution, where I don't store all 256 in a row, but only 8–16 in a two dimensional array. What do you think about that?

Comment: No. Not really.  I can see the skip loop in my head.  It reads a nibble, and adds its length to a sum. Rinse/Repeat When the sum hits 64, you have processed a character.  Best guess is that it would be pretty fast, as it is all in memory and likely to be sitting in cache a lot.  I think that some POC testing on your part is in order.

Comment: All of that fun stuff being said, it might be a good idea to simply make an API to call to fetch the desired bit pattern.   Put a static 256 x 8x8 table in it, and index into it to find the pattern.   Count the cost of that in bytes.   Then try another implementation behind the API, and Count that cost in bytes.  That would make it easy to decide which one is best for your case.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. I'll try that out.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better way to achieve this?

Rather than save the character bitmap in a rotated way, save it packed in 5 bytes.

To pack at compile time:

1. Create 32 constants (or `eunm`)

   ```
   #define L_____ 0
   #define L____X 1
   #define L___X_ 2
   ...
   #define LXXXX_ 30
   #define LXXXXX 31
   ```
2. Make macros

   ```
   #define PACK8_5(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) \
     ((((((uint64_t)(a) << 5) + (b)) << 5) + (c)) << 5) + (d) ...
   #define UNPACK40_5(a) \
     ((a) >> 32) & 31, ((a) >> 24) & 31, ((a) >> 16) & 31, ((a) >> 8) & 31, (a) & 31 
   #define CHBM(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) (UNPACK40_5(PACK8_5((a),(b),(c),(d),(e),(f),(g),(h))))
   ```
3. Make the character bit map.  What is nice about this is that the source code can look like the character bitmap.

   ```
   unsigned char letter[5] = { CHBM( \
     L__X__, \
     L_X___, \
     L_____, \
     LXXXXX, \
     LX____, \
     LXXXX_, \
     LX____, \
     LXXXXX) };
   ```

To unpack at run time - various methods possible.  Below is a simple idea.

```
void unpack5to8(unsigned char dest[8], const unsigned char src[5]) {
  uint64_t pack = src[0];
  for (unsigned i=1; i<5; i++) {
    pack <<= 8;
    pack += src[i];
  }
  for (unsigned i=8; i>0; ) {
    i--;
    dest[i] = pack & 31;
    pack >>= 5;
  }
```

Another idea would use more code but 32-bit variables.  This is where OP can profile different codes.